# Как узнать тип специализации переменной?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
template <class T>
class A {};

A<int> a;
```

Теперь, нужно объявить переменную **b** такого типа, который является специализацией **a**. (В данном случае **int**, а если бы было **A< double > a**, то **b** должна была быть объявлена как **double**)

Answer (score 3):

Если не хочется менять `class A`, тогда так:

```
template <typename T> struct foo {};
template <typename T> struct foo<A<T>> {using type = T;};
template <typename T> using foo_t = typename foo<T>::type;

A<int> a;
foo_t<decltype(a)> x; // int x
```

---

В принципе, вводить `foo_t` не обязательно. Можно каждый раз писать `typename foo<decltype(a)>::type x;`, но это довольно неудобно.

Answer (score 2):

[Такой вариант](https://ideone.com/OccRjO) не слишком пугает?...

```
template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    using type = T;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A<int> a;
    decltype(a)::type b;
    cout << typeid(b).name() << endl;
}
```

Comment: А если объекты в массиве `A<double> a[2] = {A<double>(), A<double>()};`? В этом случае `decltype(a[0])::type b;` компилятор ругается

Comment: @zhukov `std::remove_extent_t<decltype(a)>::type b;`, либо `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(a[0])>::type b;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Если массив передаётся в шаблонную функцию `func(a)`, то компилятор ругается. Прототип функции: `template<class T> void func(T a[])` В теле функции я пишу строчку: `std::remove_extent_t<decltype(a)>::type b;` на `std::remove_extent_t<decltype(a[0])>::type b;` тоже ругается

Comment: @zhukov Второй вариант сработает, но вы его переписали неточно. Там `reference` вместо `extent`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воздвигнуть что-то такое для "выдирания" любого типового аргумента по индексу

```
template <typename T, unsigned I> struct ArgTi;

template <template <typename ...> class T, typename ...Args, unsigned I>
struct ArgTi<T<Args ...>, I>
{
  using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Args ...>>::type;
};
```

а потом

```
A<int> a;
ArgTi<decltype(a), 0>::type b; // <-- int
```